# Extract API from code library

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, refactoring

Hi is there a technique available to easily extract all of the namespaces and methods etc from a code library compiled in C# for asp.net?

I basically want to be able to print all available namespaces, methods, etc so that I can decide how to refactor.

Comment: Wow! You all have great comments thanks for contributing.  I'm not sure which solution is the best for me I'll be sure to try them all :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a handy tool or not, but you can select the option to output the xml file when you compile (Project Properties->Output XML documentation file).  It will list all the methods in XML that you can import and query.  As a bonus, you will also have any xml comments that your developers have provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a tree diagram of all classes in the object browser.
The object browser is opened with the shortcut `Ctrl+W, J`.

Answer (score 1):

And I'll throw out the way to do it yourself, via reflection. Again, a lot of this depends on your requirements.

```
// get assembly from Assembly.LoadFrom or other static overload

var types = assembly.GetTypes();

var typeNames = (from t in types
        select t.FullName);

var namespaces = (from n in types
        select n.Namespace).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial tool called [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Editions.aspx) that lets you query code in many ways, and certainly supports the specific examples you mentioned.

If this is a one-time task, perhaps the trial edition would be rich enough in functionality to meet your needs.  Or maybe you'll realize how terrific it is and end up buying a copy (: (I don't have any relationship with NDepend, I just like the concepts behind that tool).

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) is great for this. It was free until about a week ago. I'm sure you could still find the free version out there somewhere or use the free trial.

From the website:

> .NET Reflector is an assembly browser
>   for the Microsoft .NET platform that
>   can be used to explore, analyze,
>   decompile, and debug the contents of
>   any .NET assembly. .NET Reflector
>   combines class browsing, static
>   analysis and high-level decompilation
>   to help .NET developers understand how
>   a library works or how it interacts
>   with other parts of a .NET
>   application. .NET Reflector will
>   decompile to high level C#, VB, IL and
>   some F# features.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which edition of Visual Studio you are using, you can create a class diagram that is then printable (I think it is available to all editions except Express). In your project, add a new file and select Class Diagram from the General category. Then drag your classes and interface files onto it's design surface.

Answer (score 0):

[SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) Will build a nice help file for you of classes/methods as well as any comments the developer made using the xml commenting.